# Making filter with Ajax / JS / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So right now im trying to create filtering through Categories / Sub Categories from the main page throught ajax, i have made it possible for 1 value to be sent to ajax file when you click on it
So first i have Categories which are like - Men / -Women / - Kids each with radio button so you can only have 1 value per item here. So after you choose your category , the subcategory will show up such as -hoodies / -pants and more this is radio aswell with another id / name so once you choose this one nothing happens the value does not get passed or showing as null , also i dont really know alot of JS or ajax im begginer here.

Button 1 for the categories

```
<div class="form-check">
        <input  name="filter" <?php if($findID == $cID) echo "checked"; ?> onload="showSubCats(this.value);" onchange="showSubCats(this.value);" class="form-check-input"  type="radio" value="<?php echo $cID; ?>" id="filter1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter1">
         <?php echo $cName; ?>
        </label>
      </div>
```

This is button 2 for the subcategories

```
  <div class="form-check">
        <input name="subFilter" onclick="showSubCats('',this.value); " class="form-check-input"  type="radio" value="<?php echo $sID; ?>" id="filter2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="filter2">
         <?php echo $sName; ?>
        </label>
      </div>
```

The values of fields come from sql query if its required i can post it here too

Here's JS / Ajax script

```
function showSubCats(val1, val2) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "ajax/filter.php",
        data: 'q='+val1+'&p='+val2,

        success: function(data){
            $("#catID").html(data);
        }
   });
};
```

Comment: there is no onload event on an input....

Comment: You might consider using a dropdown, it allows you a much larger set of selections without making life any more complex

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="subFilter" onclick="showSubCats(<?php echo $cID; ?>,this.value); " class="form-check-input"  type="radio" value="<?php echo $sID; ?>" id="filter2">
```

In my case , i had forgotten to set the Category ID from php , and aswell as i tried setting it as $cID and forgot that i had to echo it in order to show it up on the variable itself i hope this helps someone